# JavaScript How to grab the selected options in my app, to use in "if" statements to create an output in an alertbox

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement, variable-assignment

I wanna know how to use the options from my app as variables in my js. There is 20 total options, which consists of 1 drop down(5 options) and 3 sets of radio buttons(one set of 8, one set of 4, and one set of 3). With each set of possibilities to output the info that fits. I just wanna know how i can collect the chosen options from the user, and output the info that fits the options.. So how to grab clicked dropdown and radio buttons, turn into variables, and output the fitting info once the submit button is clicked.. below is the code i have, pick me apart, tell me what im doing wrong.. Am i even headed in the right direction??

Im a new student, and I'm 100% green to this. Any tips to help get me started would be greatly appreciated. I know that this project is gonna involve lots of coding using only javascript. Thanks

for ex.
Why wont this output?

```
function league(){
        var seasonSelection;
        var weekSelection;
        var timeSelection;
        var typeSelection;

        seasonSelection = seasonChoice();
        weekSelection = weekDay();
        timeSelection = timeChoice();
        typeSelction = chooseType();

        if(seasonSelection == "all" && weekSelection == "everyday" && timeSelection == "anytime" && typeSelection == "both"){
            window.alert("Solberg | Bassett Creek | 6:30PM | 5$ ");
        }

    }
```

html code

```
        <form>
            <fieldset id="apphead">
                <h2>Twin Cities Disc Golf League Finder</h2>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="season">
                <legend><span>Choose a Season</span></legend>
                <select id="pickseason">
                    <option value="all">ALL</option>
                    <option value="spring">Spring(Mar-May)</option>
                    <option value="summer">Summer(Jun-Aug)</option>
                    <option value="fall">Fall(Sep-Nov)</option>
                    <option value="winter">Winter(Dec-Feb)</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="weekday">
                <legend><span>Choose Day of the Week</span></legend>
                <label for="allweek" id="all">
                    All
                    <input type="radio" id="wkall" name="dayofweek" class="weekday" value="everyday"/>
                </label>
                <label for="monday" id="mon">
                    Mon
                    <input type="radio" id="wkmon" name="dayofweek" class="weekday" value="monday"/>
                </label>
                <label for="tuesday" id="tue">
                    Tue
                    <input type="radio" id="wktue" name="dayofweek" class="weekday" value="tuesday"/>
                </label>
                <label for="wednesday" id="wed">
                    Wed
                    <input type="radio" id="wkwed" name="dayofweek" class="weekday" value="wednesday"/>
                </label>
                <label for="thursday" id="thur">
                    Thur
                    <input type="radio" id="wkthur" name="dayofweek" class="weekday" value="thursday"/>
                </label>
                <label for="friday" id="fri">
                    Fri
                    <input type="radio" id="wkfri" name="dayofweek" class="weekday" value="friday"/>
                </label>
                <label for="saturday" id="sat">
                    Sat
                    <input type="radio" id="wksat" name="dayofweek" class="weekday" value="saturday" />
                </label>
                <label for="sunday" id="sun">
                    Sun
                    <input type="radio" id="wksun" name="dayofweek" class="weekday" value="sunday" />
                </label>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="time">
                <legend><span>Choose a Time of Day</span></legend>
                <label for="any" id="anylabel">
                    Any Time
                    <input type="radio" id="any" name="timeofday" class="selecttime" value="anytime"/>
                </label>
                <label for="flex" id="flexlabel">
                    Flex (All Day)
                    <input type="radio" id="flex" name="timeofday" class="selecttime" value="flexallday"/>
                </label>
                <label for="before" id="beforelabel">
                    Before Noon
                    <input type="radio" id="before" name="timeofday" class="selecttime" value="beforenoon"/>
                </label>
                <label for="after" id="afterlabel">
                    After Noon
                    <input type="radio" id="after" name="timeofday" class="selecttime" value="afternoon"/>
                </label>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="type">
                <legend><span>Choose Type</span></legend>
                <label for="both" id="bothlabel">
                    Both
                    <input type="radio" id="typeboth" name="ruletypes" class="selecttype" value="both"/>
                </label>
                <label for="singles" id="singleslabel">
                    Singles
                    <input type="radio" id="typesingles" name="ruletypes" class="selecttype" value="singles"/>
                </label>
                <label for="doubles" id="doubleslabel">
                    Doubles
                    <input type="radio" id="typedoubles" name="ruletypes" class="selecttype" value="doubles"/>
                </label>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="buttonbox">
                <button onclick="league()" type="button" class="submit">FIND A LEAGUE</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

JavaScript

```
    <script>





    function league(){
        var seasonSelection;
        var weekSelection;
        var timeSelection;
        var typeSelection;

        seasonSelection = seasonChoice();
        weekSelection = weekDay();
        timeSelection = timeChoice();
        typeSelction = chooseType();

        if(seasonSelection == "all" && weekSelection == "everyday" && timeSelection == "anytime" && typeSelection == "both"){
            window.alert("Solberg | Bassett Creek | 6:30PM | 5$ ");
        }

    }


    function seasonChoice(){
        var seasonChoice = document.getElementById("pickseason").value;

        return seasonChoice;
    }

    function weekDay(){
        var weekSelection = document.getElementsByClassName("weekday");
        var weekValue;
        for(var z=0; z <= 8; z++){

            if(weekSelection.checked){
                weekValue = weekSelection.value;
            }
        }
        return weekValue;
    }

    function timeChoice(){
        var timeSelection = document.getElementsByClassName("selecttime");
        var timeValue;
        for(var t=0; t <= 4; t++){

            if(timeSelection.checked){
                timeValue = timeSelection.value;
            }
        }
        return timeValue;
    }

    function chooseType(){
        var typeSelection = document.getElementsByClassName("selecttype");
        var typeValue;
        for(var y=0; y <= 3; y++){

            if(typeSelection.checked){
                typeValue = typeSelection.value;
            }
        }
        return typeValue;
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: You really need to explain your problem better. Your only actual description of the problem is in the title, and that's vague. Please make it clearer, and ask a *specific* question.

Comment: i updated it, Im soo green that im probably not even asking the my questions the right way..

Comment: When asking questions here, you must fully explain your problem, and what you expect to happen, and ask a specific question. Your question wasn't answerable before. My breaks over now, so I can't look it over, but hopefully someone can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have a typo in `function league()`. You're missing an `e` in `typeSelction = chooseType();`

Now, when you're iterating through arrays, you need the index, like this -

```
for (var z = 0; z < 8; z++) {

     if (weekSelection[z].checked) {
       weekValue = weekSelection[z].value;
     }
   }
```

You're basically missing the `z` which is the index of the array element. Similarly, `t` and `y` in other functions.

Here's [the link](http://codepen.io/anishsana/pen/QGzQBq?editors=1010#0) where you can view your full corrected working code. Also, keep in mind when iterating through arrays, do not exceed the array length, i.e., it shouldn't be `z <= 8`; it should be `z < 8`. Hope that helps!

Comment: Really appreciate the help!! i'm as noobish as they come(I'm sure that's obvious)

Comment: @cwiis05 Glad to help! If you found the answer helpful, please don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `index` while iterating over the radio selections:

```
    if (weekSelection[z].checked) { //missing [z]
      weekValue = weekSelection[z].value; //missing [z]
    }
```

Same goes for other functions

```
    if (timeSelection[t].checked) { //missing [t]
      timeValue = timeSelection[t].value; //missing [t]
    }
```

Last one:

```
    if (typeSelection[y].checked) { //missing [y]
      typeValue = typeSelection[y].value; //missing [y]
    }
```